# PyQt4 - setWindowIcon from external website

Tags: python, icons, pyqt, pyqt4

Im currently developing my first application in PyQt4, and what i would like to do now is to set my application's window icon from an image source on a website.

I thought something like this would work, but that is not the case:
self.

```
# Sets the application icon
def set_app_icon(self, icon_url):
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(QUrl(icon_url)))

self.set_app_icon('http://web.page/icon.png')
```

How can i achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: No error message, but no icon is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QIcon` cannot go and fetch data from web. You need to download it yourself and give it to `QIcon`. Something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtNetwork

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

    def loadIconFromUrl(self, url):
        manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        manager.finished.connect(self._setIconFromReply)
        manager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url)))

    def _setIconFromReply(self, reply):
        p = QtGui.QPixmap()
        p.loadFromData(reply.readAll(), format="ico")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(p))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Main()
main.loadIconFromUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico")
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!