# Get and set icon from web page on webkit pyqt4

Tags: python, user-interface, icons, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I want to use website icons as icons my Tab application. Can i get icon from loaded web page in webkit on pyqt4?
Here are some code, with method. But set icons don't work.

```
web = QtWebkit.QWebView() #in Tab Widget
#.......
web.titleChanged.connect(lambda title: titleChangedd(title))
#.....................
def titleChangedd(title):
    icon = web.icon()
    i = self.indexOf(web.parent())
    self.setWindowTitle(title) 
    self.setTabText(i, title)
    self.setTabIcon(i, QtGui.QIcon(icon))
```

How to set icon from webpage?

Comment: The API for loading website icons has always been buggy. If you do `print(icon.isNull())` it will probably output `True` for all websites regardless of whether they actually have an icon or not. I would suggest you look for some other way to get the url of the website icon, and download it yourself.

Comment: Yes, or when i print: print(icon) get really QIcon object. One of the ways  may be is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105113/pyqt4-setwindowicon-from-external-website

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
icon = web.iconUrl().url()
```